# How to copy each unique name in column to main sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a vba script to copy and paste each unique name in a column on **sheet2** to **sheet1** about 20 rows apart.

Basically i would have five unique names in a column "P" on **sheet2**, and for each unique name in that column i would want to copy and paste them to the first **sheet1** that would then also have formulas under them.

So i would want each unique name to be pasted about 20 rows apart. Then i would have unique formulas like `=sumifs`under each unique name on **sheet1**, that will then use those copied names to reference **sheet2** for analysis if that makes sense?

Comment: Show the code you have so far, so we can work with that to make it work.

Comment: I have no code so far, i honestly have no clue where to start

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub example()
Dim oldstr As String
Dim target As Range
Dim source As Range
Set source = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("p2")  'I'm assumingthis is where you start
Do  'start looping
If source.Text = oldstr Then

Else
    'new name
    Set target = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("p" & source.Row)  
    oldstr = source.Text  'update string
    target = oldstr       'write to sheet1
End If
Set source = source.Offset(1, 0) 'move down one row


Loop Until source = "" 'if cell is blank then stop
End Sub
```